# How do I echo a string to a file and call a function to hash it in the same function?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, hash

I'm trying to create a function where I pass in 2 variables. First a string to be hashed, and then a variable to specify the kind of hash, `md5` or `sha1`. This is the function I created:

```bsh
hashedWord () {
    echo $1 > pw.txt && $2 pw.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 
} > Desktop/hashedWord.txt
```

It is run as:

```
hashedWord aStringToHash, md5sum
```

where `aStringToHash` is the `$1` variable and `md5sum` (a hashing variable) is `$2`.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem really is. What is wrong with your function? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Everyone can read your password in cleartext in `pw.txt`.

Comment: thats fine, its not MY password. This was just supposed to be a quick function to make an example hashed password to use as practice with hashcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues:

- `echo` is error-prone; especially for strings you don't control it is [better use `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).
- Your variables are not quoted. --> `printf '%s' "$1"`
- You save the password in cleartext to a file. Why ??? You should pipe to your hashing algorithm directly or you'll expose your password.
- If you do that, you don't need `echo` or `printf` at all, you can use a [here-string](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_strings) --> `<<< "$1"`
- If you want, you could use `tee file` instead of `> file` to see the output on screen also.
- `Desktop/hashedWord.txt` is a relative path. If you're not in `~`, this will likely throw an error. Use an absolute path, e.g. `~/Desktop/hashedWord.txt`.

--->

```bsh
hashedWord() {
    "$2" <<< "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f1 | tee ~/Desktop/hashedWord.txt
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you, and it is not a big deal the password is saved in clear text to a file because it is not my password. This was just supposed to be a quick function to generate an EXAMPLE hash password to use with hashcat.